# I need to be able to sort a protected worksheet that has locked column headers in excel (VBA)

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on an excel document at the moment and everything is turning out quite nicely. However, I am coming down to the very last issue that I am having a problem resolving: being able to sort my columns in ascending/descending order while the worksheet is protected and the column headers are locked. I will state some facts about my worksheet first, the goal that I am trying to accomplish, then possible solutions that I have researched and why those solutions do not seem to apply to my situation.

1. First, I am **NOT** using an excel table object (just plain
   rows/columns).
2. The top row has AutoFilter applied (to work as column headers).
3. All of the cells in the worksheet are unlocked, **EXCEPT** for the
   entire first row which is locked (aka, the column headers).
4. The worksheet will be protected.
5. I do NOT want users to be able to edit data in the first row (this
   is important, these must not be editable no matter what).
6. For my protected sheet settings, I have "Select locked
   cells","Select unlocked cells","Insert rows","Delete rows","Sort",
   and "AutoFilter" checked.
7. I am using VBA for my worksheet.
8. I am using Excel 2013

Now, assuming the worksheet is protected, users are currently able to use the AutoFilter at the top to actually "filter" the data as intended. The issue is whenever they try to "sort" the data in ascending/descending order that I get an error saying that you must unprotect the sheet first.

After researching I have seen that this is due to the fact that when you sort, the AutoFilter automatically counts the column header as part of the range being sorted... but because this column header (row 1) is locked, it is causing this error. However, this row HAS to be locked, my VBA code specifically reads the values in these column headers and under no circumstances can they be changed.

So filtering works just fine, it is just the sorting I am trying to figure out now. My "ideal" solution would be to somehow capture an event when a user clicks on the AutoFilter arrow and selects "Sort" where I can then, in VBA, unprotect the sheet, sort according to their selection, then protect the sheet again. However, again upon research, it seems that there really isn't an option when it comes to an event for this AutoFilter button (I could be wrong, sometimes it can be confusing reading other's suggestions).

I am hoping someone out there can help me out with this situation, I would also LIKE to avoid using an excel table object, however if it is the only solution that works that meets all my above criteria then so-be-it.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Look into the `worksheet_change` event then you won't need to lock/protect the worksheet. You can simply prevent changes made to your header row.

Comment: I like this idea the only issue is that I pretty much need the document to stay protected to prevent anyone from copy-pasting Data Validation. I am looking for a solution that works while the document is protected.

Answer (score 2):

If you already use VBA, you can plug this code into the Sheet module. This assumes the headers are in row 1. Change to suit.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("1:1")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Application.Undo
        Application.EnableEvents = True

    End If
End Sub
```

The sheet now does not need to be protected.

Comment: I like this idea! However, the sheet unfortunately still needs to stay protected, I have Data Validation lists (drop-down options) on cells and protected sheet prevents people from copy-pasting this data to other cells (I dont want the list to override another list). So maybe if you know how to prevent this as well that could work. I still like this semi-solution and actually will use this for another project of mine, but I am curious if you know a way to do this while keeping the sheet protected?

Answer (score 0):

Borrowing a bit from @Teylyn's and adapted it to disallow selection of the header row, when it is selected, it selects the cell below it directly and displays an error message. The code sits in the sheet module, if it needs to be applied to more sheets, it may be better to use `Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)`, in that case, replace all instances of `Me` with `Sh` in the code below.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("1:1")) Is Nothing Then
        Target.Offset(1, 0).Select
        MsgBox "You cannot select or edit the headerrow, please use the autofilter button to sort and filter.", vbCritical, "Invalid Selection"
    End If
End Sub
```

### Note

Unlocking the cells which is required for the sorting and then allowing unlocked cells to be selected when protecting the worksheet, which is needed to be able to edit the data, makes the worksheet protection effectively useless.
Also wit the code above, there is still a loophole through which cells can be edited. If you select an allowed cell, drag it to the header row, and choose to replace the data in the cell then the header cell to which the allowed cell was moved is selected and editable.

### End of note

---

Select the data range which needs to be sorted and unlock the cells.

When protecting the worksheet, be sure to allow

- sort
- autofilter

To prevent users from changing the cell contents, disallow the selection of unlocked cells.

Comment: Hm, the only issue with this is that if I disallow the selection of unlocked cells then how will anyone enter in data? It is only the first row (column headers) that I do not want users to change.

Comment: Then I'd suggest keeping the cells unlocked and allow selection of the unlocked cells, tap into the `Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)` or `Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)` to prevent selection of the headers.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to make an entire row un-selectable even though the cells are unlocked?

Comment: Not as far as I know with the built in function. I've added code which disallows selection of the first row by code.